¿Como evitar que los controles TableLayoutPanel se hagan más pequeños al cerrar y abrir mi proyecto Windows Forms?
¿Qué tal?
Estoy trabajando con los contenedores TableLayoutPanel dentro de mi proyecto de Windows Forms C# .Net, los controles los tengo configurados con su respectiva propiedad anchor "Top, Left, Right", el problema es que al cerrar mi proyecto y volverlo a abrir mis controles se comprimen horizontalmente más y más, segun vaya abriendo y cerrando mi proyecto, ¿Alguien sabe que es lo que sucede o si me falto configurar alguna propiedad adicional dentro de mis tablas?
Aqui les dejo un ejemplo:

Y despues al cerrar y abrir sucede esto:

Disminuye 20 o 19 pixeles y así hasta que es practicamente muy pequeño.
En total son 4 controles  TableLayoutPanel, todos con su propiedad anchor "Top, Left, Right"
Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo se lo agradecería mucho!!

Mira, el TableLayoutPanel tiene una propiedad RowStyle que tienes que asegurarte su SizeType sea Absolute (style.SizeType==SizeType.Absolute) y si ves que eso no te funciona, ponle una width y una height fijas y entonces seguro que te funcionará.
Si no entiendes como, dime y te intento explicar mas paso a paso. Un abrazo

Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, la solución que propones permitiría que se ajuste automaticamente a cualquier pantalla? En mi formulario anterior tengo tambien configuradas las propiedades anchor de la misma manera y se ajustan automáticamente a cualquier resolución, no sé por qué dentro de este formulario se va haciendo más pequeño:(

Acabo de descubrir que el TableLayoutPanel se mueve en realidad a la izquierda al cerrar y abrir, al desactivar la propiedad anchor en "left" se mueve hacia la izquierda, y al tenerla activada creo que quiere compensarlo quitandole el tamaño como en el ejemplo que he mostrado, ¿Por qué?

Sí, el ajuste automático de tamaño podría dejar de funcionar correctamente si estableces SizeType a Absolute, no sabía que era un requerimiento que fuese responsive

Prueba a poner tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; porque así el TableLayoutPanel se ajustara automaticamente al tamaño del formulario cuando cambie de tamaño. El porque no te lo sé decir, no lo he programado yo
